# When writing an upsert procedure, is using NULL parameters an idiomatic way to handle cases where the primary key only exists in the update case?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, merge, upsert

I have a table that has one column, an auto-increment column, as its primary key. It has no other unique keys. I wish to write a stored procedure that upserts in to it. Because it only has one unique key, the primary key, I believe that the only way to uniquely identify a row that already exists is by using the primary key. This means that my stored procedure must have the primary key as one of its arguments. However, on the insert side of the upsert coin, there is no row with the desired primary key. This means that the caller of the upserting stored procedure cannot know the value of the primary key. I've therefore concluded that the primary key must be an argument to my upsert stored procedure but must also be allowed to be passed as a `NULL` value.

**Is this an idiomatic solution to the problem that I've described?** I'm not used to seeing `NULL` parameters in SQL and I get very uneasy when I write `MERGE` clauses with lines like

```
--Part of MERGE
--Assume a [Source] table has been built from the parameters.
--e.g. [Source].[PrimaryKey] = @PrimaryKeyParam
ON `[Source].[PrimaryKey]` IS NOT NULL AND [Target].[PrimaryKey] = [Source].[PrimaryKey]
```

Comment: I don't follow, if the criteria for an update or insert is that the row already exists in the table and the calling code doesn't have the thing that would be used to identify this then how are you expecting it to work?

Comment: If the caller knows they need to insert they should just call an insert statement

Comment: @MartinSmith My point is that the insert code doesn't need to - and in fact can't - know the primary key. Said primary key is an auto-increment column.

Comment: @MartinSmith So you're saying that if I already know the primary key value in the update case and don't know it in the insert case, then I should just write an update procedure and an insert procedure (both with different arguments, because they have different knowledge) rather than one upsert procedure?

Comment: yes. The point of `MERGE` isn't so you can have one bit of code to call for all your insert/update needs. If you know what you need to do (which you will do) you should just call the dedicated statement. Will likely be better performing and you don't have to concern yourself with whether or not any of the bugs with MERGE will affect you

Comment: See "Performance Tip" in the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @MartinSmith Oh, I didn't do that for performance: I did it out of stupidity. My thoughts were simply "I need to update if the row's already there and insert otherwise, so I therefore need to upsert, and upsert means `MERGE`!". Clearly I was wrong. Feel free to post an answer explaining why I don't need to `MERGE` and was silly to. I'll accept it.

Comment: Regardless of the methodology you use for UPSERT - how are you going to identify when a row already exists and an attempt to insert that row should fail?  If the only thing you have is the PK and that is an identity column then you are *guaranteeing* duplicate rows will be inserted.  If the answer is a combination of columns - then that is the unique key you need to define.  If the answer is all of the columns, then I think you need to step back and re-think the design of that table.

Comment: Doesn't doing an equality predicate on [Source].[PrimaryKey] already imply that it's not null? That is, no value can both equal something and be null so the check for not null seems redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's pretty idiomatic to have a procedure that accepts a @PK param that can be NULL for inserts. Usually, you want to return the inserted ID back to client, so it can also be an OUTPUT parameter.
Otherwise, i think INSERT / UPDATE is less chance to muck up than MERGE. So something like:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE SPRC_SOMETHING_SAVE (
 @PK INT OUTPUT
, @Field1 VARCHAR(30)
...
)
AS
BEGIN
IF @PK IS NULL
BEGIN
   INSERT...
   --
   SET @PK = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  UPDATE ...
  FROM TABLE t
  WHERE t.PK = @PK
END
END
```